# Изменить шейдерный цвет из кода

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня в материале есть шейдер, цвет в котором имеет такой вид:

> _ColorFront("Color Front", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

Как я могу из кода менять этот цвет?

Ведь просто material.color меняет значении строго с названием _Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity3D Uniform пермеменные в шейдер нужно передавать при помощи методов материала [`SetColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html), [`SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html) и так далее в зависимости от типа данных.

В вашем случае это что-то такое (строкой тут задается фактическое имя переменной внутри шейдера)

```
material.SetColor("_ColorFront", Color.red);
```